# Select elements from different tables. Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have table called *shopdb* that constants  there tables which are: **customer** - **product**- and **receipt**. Each has some data i want to select elements from the tables in one field, which is after  15th day of the month
for more clarification  see the photo below:

[Show the purchases made by Veronica Lim which is after the 15th day of the month.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcfn1.png)

I tried to attempt i end with this code:

```
SELECT Cust_Name , Cust_State ,Rec_Quantity ,Rec_Date, Prod_Name from product , receipt , customer where Cust_Name ="Veronica Lim" and Rec_Date  > '2017-04-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing the other fields in the tables but you will likely need to join on a primary key field from one table to a foreign key on the other tables which will look something like this (depending on the keys):

```
SELECT C.CUST_NAME, C.CUST_STATE, R.REC_QUANTITY, R.REC_DATE, P.PROD_NAME 
FROM CUSTOMER C 
  INNER JOIN RECEIPT R ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = R.CUSTOMER_ID
  INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON R.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE CUST_NAME = 'Veronica Lim' 
  AND REC_DATE > '2017-04-15'
```

If you run into errors you might need to double check that the aliases (individual letters below) are correct for each field in the `SELECT` statement and that the date format is right.